# Reverse the nesting order in sass

Tags: sass

My sass -

```
.form-control{
   .label{
        //reversing the nesting order:
       .lg & {  

       }
   }
}
```

produces css -

```
.lg  .form-control .label {

}
```

But I would like to have in css -

```
.lg .label {

}

or//
.form-control .lg .label {

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, that's what nesting in SASS is about.

So instead, write this:

```
.form-control{
   .label{
       .lg & {  
         // really specific styling
       }
   }
}
```

And this:

```
.lg .label {
  // more general styling
}
```

Combined that can become powerful. Too much nesting will always end up with too specific styling rules and usually there's more of a down side to it, as it being really helpful.

**Note**: as mentioned you can use the `@at-root` directive, to avoid that issue.
`@at-root`applied on a children will by default skip the `parent` and target the `root`.

Like this:

```
.item {
    color: #333;

    @at-root {
        .item-wrapper {
            color: #666;

            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
    
    .item-child {
        background-color: #555;
    }
}
```

Will compile to:

```
.item {
  color: #333;
}
.item-wrapper {
  color: #666;
}
.item-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
.item .item-child {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

By using `with` or `without` you can either add or remove specific rules.
Here's the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root).

Comment: what about @at-root .lg .label ?

Comment: @s.k.paul. Oh, yes you'r right, didn't think into that. I'll edit my answer for you.